# conda install sklearn_crfsuite not working in spyder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder, conda

I am new to spyder, and trying to figure out how to install sklearn_crfsuite. This is the error i get while installing in spyder ipython console :

Command : conda install sklearn_crfsuite

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - sklearn_crfsuite;
```

Spyder version : 3.2.8

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Have you tried `conda install -c conda-forge python-crfsuite` (see [here](http://github.com/scrapinghub/python-crfsuite)? I ask as this installed the package for me on Windows, but then when I try to import it (`import import sklearn_crfsuite`), Spyder gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_crfsuite'`, even though this import works fine on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this.

If a package is not available from conda or Anaconda.org, you may be able to find and install the package with another package manager like pip.

```
Step 1 : install pip in current conda environment with the command 'conda install pip'
Step 2 : install the required package with the command 'pip install sklearn_crfsuite'
Step-3 : verify package is installed with the command 'conda list'
```

Reference : https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21157016)

Comment: @SambhavSharma, Sure. Will do the same. :)